# The black coffee vs coffee black

Tags: grammar

These two sentence are grammatically correct or not

He served the coffee black

He served the black coffee

What is difference in there meaning

Comment: What do you think is the difference?

Comment: In the first sentence you can think of *black* as an adverb of *served* which puts focus more on the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, they are both correct; however, :

> He served the black coffee

This is because "black" is used to describe the actual type of coffee. The second one has a different meaning in this case because it means that the coffee is "black", meaning it has no cream or sugar, which is the condition of the coffee. The grammar of the first sentence can be better understood correctly with this example:

> He served the sandwich cold

This is actually describing the state, or in this case temperature, of the sandwich, To clarify, the difference is that the second sentence **directly describes** the coffee (in this case, the type of coffee), while the first sentence *generally* **states the condition** of the coffee.

This is the difference between *ser* and *estar* in **Spanish**, with *ser* directly describing objects and things that are permanent (hair color, origin, etc.) and *estar* stating conditions of objects and things that are temporary (health, emotion, etc.)

Additionally, "coffee black" can also refer to a shade of black. Here are some examples of this:

> - Rose Gold
> - Sky Blue
> - Space Gray

Comment: -1 Black is a state or way of taking coffee (as in not with cream and/or sugar) and the first sentence correctly describes this.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, I was correct about the state of condition